# how to highlight the selected menu in angular 4

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to highlight the selected menu but unable to get an idea.

Below code is menu with sub-menus, menus come from JSON.

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let values of val">
    <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-ripple" mat-button routerLink=".">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header expandedHeight="48px" collapsedHeight="48px">
            <mat-panel-title>
                <md-icon class="mat-icon mat-list-icon material-icons">
                    {{values.titleImage}}
                </md-icon>
                <div class="menu-list-text">
                    {{values.titleName}}
                </div>
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <a class="sidenav-link mat-list-item mat-ripple"
           mat-button
           routerLink="."
           *ngFor="let subTitleVal of values.subTitle">
            <div class="mat-list-item-content">
                <span md-line="">{{subTitleVal.titleName}}</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</div>
```

**JSON**

```
val: any;
val = [{
    'titleKey': 'AAA',
    'titleName': ' Menu1',
    'titleImage': 'Icon1',
    'subTitle': [{
        'titleKey': 'AAA',
        'titleName': 'SubMenu1',
        'action': 'ACC',
    }]
}, {
    'titleKey': 'BBB',
    'titleName': 'Menu2',
    'titleImage': 'Icon2',
    'subTitle': [{
        'titleKey': 'BBB',
        'titleName': 'SubMenu2',
        'action': 'FT',
    }]
}, {
    'titleKey': 'CCC',
    'titleName': 'Menu3',
    'titleImage': 'Icon3',
    'subTitle': [{
        'titleKey': 'CCC',
        'titleName': 'SubMenu3',
        'action': 'BP',
    }]
}];
```

How to add the class when user selects a particular sub-menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`routerLinkActive`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) attribute on `a` element to specify css class to be used for the link that corresponds to the selected route.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a addClass and removeClass like:

```
import { Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class changeStyleClass {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  addClass( element: any, className: string) {
  this.renderer.addClass(element, className);
  // or use the host element directly
  // this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, className);
  }

  removeClass(className: string, element: any) {
  this.renderer.removeClass(element, className);
  }

}
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/BpeYpqf378MYDLWRGbjc?p=preview